# openssl decrypt function not working properly after php upgrade

Tags: php, openssl

I have a PHP application that is using `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt`, it has been working fine for the past four years.
Recently, the app is showing `false` when it calls `openssl_decrypt` function.

This is the encryption part:

```
<?php
$password = "iR0nM@N2017!?KOreVoNick";
$method = "aes128";
$iv = "69kjg23423L@cEv7";

$montant = htmlentities($_POST['montant'])-$mutation;
$numeroCheque = openssl_encrypt(htmlentities($_POST['numeroCheque']), $method, $password, 0, $iv);
$designationSociete = openssl_encrypt(htmlentities($_POST['designationSociete']), $method, $password, 0, $iv);
$designationPersonne = openssl_encrypt(htmlentities($_POST['designationPersonne']), $method, $password, 0, $iv);
$dateCheque = htmlentities($_POST['dateCheque']);
$idProjet = htmlentities($_POST['idProjet']);
$createdBy = $login;
$created = date('d/m/Y h:m');
$statut = htmlentities($_POST['statut']);
$compteBancaire = openssl_encrypt(htmlentities($_POST['compteBancaire']), $method, $password, 0, $iv);
$url = "";
$cheque = new Cheque(array('numero' => $numeroCheque , 'montant' => $montant,
    'designationSociete' => $designationSociete, 'designationPersonne' => $designationPersonne, 
    'dateCheque' => $dateCheque, 'idProjet' =>$idProjet, 'idSociete' => $idSociete, 'compteBancaire' => $compteBancaire, 'createdBy' => $createdBy, 'created' => $created,
    'statut' => $statut, 'url' => $url));
    $chequeManager = new ChequeManager($pdo);
    $chequeManager->add($cheque);
```

And for decryption it's easy as this:

```
    openssl_decrypt($cheque->numero(), $method, $password, 0, $iv);
```

And this is the error I get when I use `openssl_error_string()`

```
'error:0607A082:digital envelope routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the contents of `$cheque->numero()` ?

Comment: $cheque->numero() it;s a string

Comment: Would probably be useful to see the other half of this process, can you show your encrypt code

Comment: I'm guessing that the key you have in your question is not the same as the one in your program, which is sensible. try it with on ethe exact same length and see if you get the error still...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the other part of code. The weird thing is that this same code was working just fine for 4 years ;)

Comment: It helps if the code you show us actually works. [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: have you upgraded php in the past 4 years? which php version are you running now?
and the code you have posted would work better if you had sample values for the `$_POST['variable']` entries. as is i can't run it, as @RiggsFolly writes, it ought to be a [mcve]. besides, the cheque class is now found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following:

```php
<?php

$cleartext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$password = "iR0nM@N2017!?KOreVoNick";
$method = "aes128";
$iv = "69kjg23423L@cEv7";

$enctext = openssl_encrypt($cleartext, $method, $password, 0, $iv);

$dectext = openssl_decrypt($enctext, $method, $password, 0, $iv);
header("content-type:text/plain");

echo "decrypted: $dectext\n\n";
echo "encrypted: $enctext\n\n";
echo "orig: $cleartext\n";
```

### Result

```
decrypted: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

encrypted: fyYcGEVOpH9cEZuBIN4S1GRDp/kU+Kzv1UJUp2UBGpPv/R+BxxbBDArKa+ugvOOr

orig: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Therefore my conclusion is that you have some issue with the length or padding of what you are decrypting.

### PHP version:

`Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.3`